# Why .each here doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

```
["1", "2"].map { |x| x + "." }
#=> ["1.", "2."] 

["1", "2"].each { |x| x + "." }
#=> ["1", "2"]
```

Both methods apply a block on each element, I can't really understand why `each` doesn't do anything

Comment: I've seen this question many times in different guises. The short answer is that `map` and `each` are different methods. Would you ask why `map` and `select` don't return the same value? If not, then why `map` and `each`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each) worked. It just iterated and yields one element per iteration inside the block. Once completed, it returns the object `["1", "2"]` you called it on. To see, that each is called do like :

```
["1", "2"].each {|x| p( x + "." ) }
 # "1."
 # "2."
```

But [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map) - Invokes the given block once for each element of self. Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.